# Moved Textures To Different Folders

Tags: texturing, materials, image

So I am trying to fix my blender installation and have an issue where the texture files are no longer where they were when the file was created many moons and hard drives ago. I know where all the texture files are now, but have several dozens of blender files to deal with.

Is there a resource for the format of the blender file so that I could just write a quick program to fix everything?

Or has someone already done this?

I would rather not have to open each file and fix every texture one by one.

Comment: What do you mean by "the format of the blender file"? If you mean its location, a short expression for this in Blender's Python library is `bpy.path.abspath("//")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `Find Missing Files`. can be automated with `bpy.ops.file.find_missing_files()`.
I'd probably leverage the python API rather than messing with the blend file format. Execute `blender.exe --python your_fixup_script.py need_fixing.blend`

[image]

Comment: I could work with that just on a file by file basis, it's not super critical to make them all be up to date. Still knowing the file format I could also scan the files and build a excel worksheet with locations and names and figure out the best strategy to tackling the issue. I should note that textures are in multiple folders.

Comment: I haven't messed with the blend file format, but considering there may be differences between versions I'd rather use the same method I mentioned to extract the paths. I've done something similar to mass export meshes.